# I want the if statement to work when it is or over 12 minutes, but i keep getting an error saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean"

Tags: java, if-statement, time

I want the if statement to run when it is or passed 12 minutes, but I keep getting the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean", how can I get through this?

```
public void clock() {
    Thread cloo = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                    int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    lblNewLabel_1.setText(day + "/ " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + second);
                    sleep(1000);

                    if (min =+ 12) { // <<<<< where the problem is
                        message.setText("its been over 12 minutes");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have `min >= 12`. `min =+ 12` is adding 12 to the current amount of minutes.

Comment: The answer is correct. This is for your future help, try debugging the code step by step and know the return value at the step where the issue is, you will get the source of it.

Comment: @Tyberius: No, `min =+ 12` doesn't add 12 minutes - that would be `min += 12`. `min =+ 12` is equivalent to `min = +12;` so it's just setting the value to 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` expression only accept a `boolean` value, but `min =+ 12` is a `int` value, so type mismatch happens.

try this:

```
int countdown = 12;
while (true) {
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    lblNewLabel_1.setText(day + "/ " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + second);

    sleep(1000);
    countdown = countdown - 1;

    if (countdown <= 0) {
        message.setText("its been over 12 minutes");
    }
}
```

Further, depends on your programming design, you should decide what to do when the time passes over 12 minutes, stop it or re-countdown? The code above will execute `message.setText("its been over 12 minutes");` repeatly.